# What is the best way to toggle a boolean variable?

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to have a variable toggle between `true` and `false`? An obvious way is to initialize a variable `foo`:

```
foo = false
```

and do:

```
foo = foo.!
```

every time when I want to toggle. But this becomes verbose when the variable name is long. Is there a simpler way to do this (by using anything such as syntax sugar, original classes)? Especially, I wonder if there is a way to toggle by just giving it a single method:

```
foo.some_method
```

Comment: Using `foo.!` is IMHO quite ugly. Why not `foo = !foo`?

Comment: Agree with @ŁukaszNiemier foo = !foo more ruby style way

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the `!` method. The suggestion from @ŁukaszNiemier is more typical, as it's also used in double form to take a variable whose value may not be a boolean and convert it to boolean. `foo = 1; foo = !!foo;`.

Comment: `foo.!` is a Ruby method, which means it it the Ruby way. Furthermore, one characteristics of Ruby is to allow method chaining. `!foo` does not allow chaining, and is more ugly.

Comment: `foo.some_method` syntax is going to be hard in Ruby, because `some_method` gets sent to the object, not the variable. You might be able to create a variable-modifying global method `toggle` and do something like `toggle :foo` I guess

Comment: @NeilSlater You're absolutely right.

Comment: If I were you I would create class `Switch` with methods: `switch`, `on`, `off`, `state`, `on?`, `off?`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use XOR operator.

```
foo ^= true
```

---

```
foo = false
foo ^= true # => true
foo ^= true # => false
```

Comment: It works, but it is not common knowledge and many people will simply not understand this when seen in your code. If there is any chance other programmers will be looking at and maintaining your code, you should use the standard negation with `!`.

Comment: @Nate I thought it was common knowledge that when you xor something with true (or if it's a bit, `1`) it's logical value (true/false, or 1/0) toggles. At least it's well known in the world of bit twiddlers. It's basic boolean logic. If a software engineer can't quickly figure that out, then I'd be concerned.

Comment: A downside for me is that this only works with true/false, whereas a lot of the time predicate methods return truthy values rather than true (e.g. regex match returns index of the match)

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes, the technique given in this solution is for toggling a boolean variable on the lhs (left hand side) of the `=`. If you have a `regex`, it's on the rhs.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
module Fickle
  refine TrueClass do
    def toggle!
      false
    end
  end

  refine FalseClass do
    def toggle!
      true
    end
  end
end

using Fickle

a = true.toggle!
puts a # Output: false

b = false.toggle!
puts b # Output: true
```